# How to make a img flicker using css(should work in all browsers)

Tags: css

```
.name{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition:opacity 2s;

}

.students img:hover{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Right now I am able to change the opacity on the hover but I want the image to flicker i.e. the opacity should go to 0 then come back to 1 then again go to 0 and come back to 1 like flickering. Hope I was able explain my problem

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting to use jQuery or simple javascript for that purpose.
For example:

```
$(function () 
{
    flicker();
    function flicker () 
    {           
        $('#test').fadeIn(100, function ()
        {
            $('#test').fadeOut(150, function () 
            {                    
               setTimeout(flicker, 50);               
            });
        });
    }

});
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zvp85/)

You can set the speed of the flickering by modifying the first parameter of fadeIn, fadeOut function and the second one of the setTimeout. Please note they are in milliseconds.

**EDIT**

I've found the how to do this with CSS3 only.
Here is the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kXHJ/)